# read txt file but don't display last line

Tags: php

Is it possible to read a txt file except for the last line?
the last line is a blank line and gives a pagination 'blank' page

```
<!-- the input fields that will hold the variables we will use -->
      <input type='hidden' id='current_page' />
    <input type='hidden' id='show_per_page' />


<div id='content'> 


    <?php
$file = fopen("admin/events/events.txt", "r");
while(!feof($file)){
    $line = fgets($file);
$line = str_replace("<div data-role='day' data-day='", "<b><u>Datum:</b></u> ", $line);
$line = str_replace("'><div data-role='event' data-name='<h1>", " <br><b><u>Event:</b></u> ", $line);
$line = str_replace("' data-start='", " <br><b><u>Start:</b></u> ", $line);
$line = str_replace("' data-end='", " <br><b><u>Einde:</b></u> Tot ", $line);
$line = str_replace("' data-location='", " <br><b><u>Locatie:</b></u> ", $line);
$line = str_replace("</h1>", " <br><b><u>Inhoud event:</b></u><br> ", $line);
$line = str_replace("'></div></div>", "", $line);
echo "<div class='event'>$line</div>"; 
}
fclose($file);

?>

</div>
<br>
<div id='page_navigation'></div>
```

so it gives page 1 2 3 4 and page 123 are filled with content, but page 4 is blank because the last line in the txt file is always a newline because i write to the txt fil with PHP_EOL for newline creation. How can i read all lines in the txt file, except for the last line?

Comment: Could you do if(empty($line)) continue;  Or do you want to read other empty lines, but not the last one?

Comment: hi, no there are no other empty lines, only the last line...i will give it a try :) thx for your effort

Comment: I think Bart's answer needs to be accepted, to prevent others from trying (and failing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`empty`](http://php.net/empty) might not work, as it doesn't consider a newline as empty. [`trim`](http://php.net/trim) first:

```
$line = trim($line);
if ($line != "") {
   // process line
}
```

Better though, is to really fix it and use a decent HTML DOM parser to read the file. (It seems to be HTML.)

Answer (score 1):

Since you said that there are no other empty lines you can definitely do something along the lines of:

```
// open file ...
while(!feof($file))
{
  $line = fgets($file);
  if( empty($line) ) continue;
  // ...
}
```

This may give you some weird issues if you will have line that has only the number '0' on it. [Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) So you may want to substitute it for

```
  if ( $line === "" )
```

which is a little harder to read, but is more precise.

If you must have other empty lines, but not the last one, you could just output the line on the next pass. So you do:

```
// open file ...
$next = fgets($file)
while(!feof($file))
{
  $line=$next;
  // ...
  $next = fgets($file);
}
```

Comment: word 'false'? are you sure?

Comment: The string `'0.0'` is not empty to `empty()`.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just check again if the file end was reached?

```
while(!feof($file)){
$line = fgets($file);

if (!feof($file))
{
//do what you need - it wasn't the last line
}

}
```

This way you'll skip last line even if it's not empty

Answer (score -1):

Just omit it if it's empty! After reading `$line = fgets($file);` in next line check if it's empty if so then just `continue`. You want to continue because if it's some more content in the file and you are in the middle of it you don't want to exit, you want to continue to next line. If it's last empty line then while loop will end anyway.

```
    while(!feof($file)){  
       $line = fgets($file);
       if(empty($line)) {
         continue;
       } else {
         $line = str_replace("<div data-role='day' data-day='", "<b><u>Datum:</b></u> ", $line);
         // ... end rest of your code
       }
    }
```

while(!feof($file)){
    $line = fgets($file);
$line = str_replace("Datum: ", $line);
$line = str_replace("'>", " 
**Event:** ", $line);
$line = str_replace("' data-start='", " 
**Start:** ", $line);
$line = str_replace("' data-end='", " 
**Einde:** Tot ", $line);
$line = str_replace("' data-location='", " 
**Locatie:** ", $line);
$line = str_replace("", " 
**Inhoud event:**
 ", $line);
$line = str_replace("'>", "", $line);
echo "$line"; 
}
    ...

Comment: @user555 type to fast.. corrected :) did you put this -1? if so can you give me it back please :)

Comment: @YourCommonSense I've update my snippet, so now should be clear. If no please let me know..

Comment: Its still unclear why `else`. Do you really need it?

Comment: you don't need to use it, but this don't mean you need to omit it. This code is valid with or without ```else```.

Comment: @YourCommonSense If you think you know better solution just write your own answer ;)

Comment: BTW, on my screen nested code in else block turns on horizontal scrolling.